# How do you publish/embed a swf with flexible size?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

How to make the swf scale as necessary?

So far all swf embedded into a web page are fixed in size, how to make it flexible?

Answer (score 0):

The size of a swf in a HTML page is defined by the `<embed>` tag and the swf application's attributes like `width` and `height`. Let's say you did not define the `maxwidth` and `maxheight` of your swf app (they default to zero which means that there is no maximum) and you set the `width` and `height` to `100%`. Now, to be able to resize you swf, you only have to resize its container which can be a `DIV` for example. `DIV` can be resized easily using javascript, here is a jQuery plugin - http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Comment: But the size is controled by swf itself,which is flexible.

Comment: Do you mean that you have controls to resize the swf inside the swf?